# How to set tab background color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to set the colour of all the white space in a tab that I have using `QSS`. 
In the image you see what it currently looks like.

[image]

This next image is what happens if I use

> "background-color:black;"

[image]

You can see that it *HAS* made the background black, but I want to fill in the surrounding white area too.

*Anyone know how this is done?*

I have my items collected together in various `QHBoxLayout`

Comment: You have to apply that style to the parent as well. So, if you have a set of nested elements you will need to apply the style to the top most element. If you supply your CSS and HTML of the area we may be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes! I found the parent! Thanks so much!